# OpenGL - Stencil, Requesting for information and pointer

Tags: opengl, glsl

Is it possible to make a Cube notch another cube without notching its neighbour via id? See small 2D sketch below.

I think I need to make a custom stencil shader GLSL (set 0 and 1 myself, is it possible?). but then how would I achieve that?? And just to make it more impossible, I would like to color the notched side.

**In other words, On OpenGL I would like to achieve this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AGJ_Pk28UnA&t=438s&ab_channel=WorldofZero and make it notch a specific object ID**

*Special note: I am not making a video game, so I don't care a lot about the performance.*

[image]

Comment: Anyone? have a solution